# Why does Testcontainers not use application.properties / application.yaml?

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers, application.properties

In my Spring Boot 2.4.3 application I use Testcontainers and I followed the instructions found on the internet. I have an `application.yaml`:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:13.2:///testdb?TC_INITSCRIPT=tc_initscript_postgresql.sql
    username: duke
    password: s3crEt
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```

but when I debug the application the container has always 'test' as the value for URL, username and password.

Here's my test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractApplicationIT {

    final static DockerImageName POSTGRES_IMAGE = DockerImageName.parse("postgres:13.2-alpine");

        @Container
    //    public static GenericContainer postgreSQLContainer = new GenericContainer(POSTGRES_IMAGE)
        public static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(POSTGRES_IMAGE)
    //            .withInitScript("tc_initscript_postgresql.sql")
    //            .withPassword("password")
    //            .withUsername("username")
    //            .withDatabaseName("test")
    //            .withInitScript("tc_initscript_postgresql.sql")
                ;
    
    //    @DynamicPropertySource
    //    static void postgresqlProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    //        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgreSQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
    //        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgreSQLContainer::getPassword);
    //        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgreSQLContainer::getUsername);
    //    }
    
        @Test
        public void contextLoads() {
            System.out.println(postgreSQLContainer.getDatabaseName());
            System.out.println(postgreSQLContainer.getUsername());
            System.out.println(postgreSQLContainer.getPassword());
        }
    
    }
```

The System.out:

> test 
> test 
> test

...even without using `@DynamicPropertySource`.

Comment: I guess that containers are started before the processing of `application.properties` files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The container don't know the application.properties.

application.properties is Spring Boot configuration and have nothing to do with Testcontainers.

You can override values like this

```
@Container
private PostgreSQLContainer postgresqlContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer()
    .withDatabaseName("foo")
    .withUsername("foo")
    .withPassword("secret");
```

You can also read the values from the application.properties like this:

```
@Value("spring.datasource.username")
private String username;
```

Comment: Well, but what I want is to not hardcode these values but rather read them from application.yaml.

Comment: You can always read this values with @Value. Checkout my edited answer

Comment: Well, okay. That means that I can't instantiate the Container in a static way in an abstract super (test) class but have to create a container for each concrete test case.

Comment: @DynamicPropertySource seems to me a completely senseless annotation (at least for Testcontainers or...this scenario). Using it I always have to hardcode the values.

Answer (score 0):

Testconainers can derive the container definition from your `spring.datasource.url` using its [JDBC support](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/).

A minimal example can look like the following:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {
  "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:12:///springboot?TC_INITSCRIPT=somepath/init_mysql.sql"
})
class AbstractApplicationIT {
 
  @Autowired
  private YourRepository yourRepository;
 
  @Test
  @Sql("/scripts/INIT_THREE_ORDERS.sql")
  void shouldReturnOrdersThatContainMacBookPro() {
    List<Order> orders = yourRepository.findAllContainingMacBookPro();
    assertEquals(2, orders.size());
  }
}
```

For this to work, don't manually specify any additional container definition inside your test.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue on this - https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4121

According to the documentation, JDBC URL is supported in host-less URI format and this fact is emphasized through multiple examples. It seems there is a parsing issue in code, which ignores the database name, if it doesn't find host and port fields. You've to put the host and port to let the database field be accepted, anyways host and port fields will be ignored.